# Multi-domain routing/redirecting

Tags: php, dns, hosting

I have 6 domain names. Lets say:

```
www.abc.com
www.abc1.com
www.abc2.com
www.abc3.com
www.abc4.com
www.abc5.com
```

But I have only one php hosting for www.abc.com
I redirected all pages to www.abc.com

How can I detect that which domain name the visitor came from?

Comment: you can't get it by `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

From the doc:

> 'HTTP_REFERER' The address of the page (if any) which referred the
>   user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all
>   user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify
>   HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted